# C, reading multiple numbers from a single line ignoring the whitespaces

Tags: c, numbers, scanf, fgets, c-strings

I am working on a problem where I need to input a line of numbers with one or more whitespaces in between and add the numbers. But I am having a problem with ignoring the whitespaces.

I have tried using scanf(" ") and scanf("%*c"). 
What is the most efficient way to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the number of numbers fixed or variable?

Comment: @Jabberwocky variable

Comment: What _exactly_ should the user type for, say 3 values: `1 2 3<Enter>`?, <Enter> meaning "press the Enter key".

Comment: What should happen if the user enter non numerals like e.g. `1 2 ab 3`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky It is assumed that the line will only consist of integers and whitespaces.

Comment: Please answer my second comment. Everything I've asked in the comments is essential information that needs to be in the question. It's part of your specification.

Answer (score 2):

If the number of input integers in an entered string is unknown then you can use the approach shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 100 };
    char line[N];

    while ( fgets( line, N , stdin ) != NULL && line[0] != '\n' && line[0] != '\0' )
    {
        long long int sum = 0;

        const char *s = line;
        char *p = line;

        do
        {
            s = p;
            sum += strtol( s, &p, 10 );
        } while ( s != p );

        printf( "sum = %lld\n", sum );
    }

    return 0;

}
```

If to enter string

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

then the output will be

```
sum = 15
```

Answer (score 1):

To read integers, use the format string %d, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int sum, i, n;

    sum = 0;
    n = scanf("%d", &i);
    while (n == 1) {
        sum += i;
        n = scanf("%d", &i);
    }
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to read real numbers, use the format string %lf (which stands for long float) and adjust the code above accordingly.

Comment: With this solution the input must be ended via EOF (Ctr-D).

Answer (score -1):

The way to do it in C++ would be

```
double a;
double b;
double c;

std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
```

I am not sure if you can do something very similar in C, please tell me if that was helpful.